# keras/tensorflow error on training with user-provided loss function ("Error in py_call_impl [...] ValueError: in user code")

Tags: python, r, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

The following keras model produces the error given below when trained with a user-provided loss function. Here is the MWE (just using a dummy loss function to demonstrated the problem):

```
library(keras)

## Set up the model
in.lay <- layer_input(shape = 2)
out.lay <- layer_dense(in.lay, units = 2, activation = "sigmoid")
model <- keras_model(in.lay, out.lay)

## Compile
NN <- compile(model, optimizer = "adam", loss = function(x, y = out.lay) 1) # dummy loss function; fit() below fails

## Train
n <- 10000
set.seed(271)
data <- matrix(runif(n * 2), ncol = 2) # dummy training data
prior <- qnorm(matrix(runif(n * 2), ncol = 2)) # dummy prior data
fit(NN, x = prior, y = data, batch_size = 1000, epochs = 10) # training (fails with the error below)
```

And here is the error message I get:

```
Epoch 1/10
Error in py_call_impl(callable, dots$args, dots$keywords) :
  ValueError: in user code:

    /usr/local/tensorflow/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:571 train_function  *
        outputs = self.distribute_strategy.run(
    /usr/local/tensorflow/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:951 run  **
        return self._extended.call_for_each_replica(fn, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
    /usr/local/tensorflow/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:2290 call_for_each_replica
        return self._call_for_each_replica(fn, args, kwargs)
    /usr/local/tensorflow/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:2649 _call_for_each_replica
        return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    /usr/local/tensorflow/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:532 train_step  **
        loss = self.compiled_loss(
    /usr/local/tensorflow/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/compile_util
```

Note that the above model trains well if another loss function is provided, for example with `NN <- compile(model, optimizer = "adam", loss = loss_mean_squared_error)`, the `fit()` call works flawlessly. Also note that I could previously use user-provided loss functions and had no problems with that, so this might be due to an R package, TensorFlow, Keras, etc. update (I don't know). Calling `debug(keras:::fit.keras.engine.training.Model)` before the `fit()` call reveals that `history <- do.call(object$fit, args)` inside `keras:::fit.keras.engine.training.Model()` fails, but neither `object$fit` nor `args` looks suspicious. Here is my `sessionInfo()` in `R`:

```
sessionInfo()

R version 4.0.4 (2021-02-15)

Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin20.3.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS Big Sur 11.5.2

Matrix products: default
BLAS:   /usr/local/R/R-4.0.4_build/lib/libRblas.dylib
LAPACK: /usr/local/R/R-4.0.4_build/lib/libRlapack.dylib

locale:
[1] en_CA.UTF-8/en_CA.UTF-8/en_CA.UTF-8/C/en_CA.UTF-8/en_CA.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base

other attached packages:
[1] keras_2.3.0.0.9000

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_1.0.7       lattice_0.20-41  here_1.0.1       png_0.1-7
 [5] rprojroot_2.0.2  zeallot_0.1.0    rappdirs_0.3.3   grid_4.0.4
 [9] R6_2.5.0         jsonlite_1.7.2   magrittr_2.0.1   tfruns_1.4
[13] whisker_0.4      Matrix_1.3-2     reticulate_1.22  generics_0.1.0
[17] compiler_4.0.4   base64enc_0.1-3  tensorflow_2.6.0
```

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63074442/error-in-py-call-implcallable-dotsargs-dotskeywords-valueerror-in-user) or [this](https://community.rstudio.com/t/keras-and-tensaflow-error/75751) post might be related (but are unanswered).

Comment: your keras version is quite outdated, please run `install.packages("keras")` to update to the latest version. Also, this might fail because your dummy loss function needs to return a value that tensorflow get gradient to update weights from, you're return a value that will be disconnected from the graph because it's not derived from the function inputs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized that the way I start R has changed after an update and the above errors were produced when running R *not* inside the required Python environment. The problem entirely disappeared after I started R from within the Python environment within which TensorFlow is running.